# How to enable or disable the Debug Toolbar on Oracle WebCenter Content Server

Tags: oracle, content-management-system, oracle-ucm, webcenter, stellent

When logged in with Administrator rights on Oracle WebCenter Content Server (formerly Oracle UCM which also was Stellent Content Server), a debug toolbar shows up on the bottom right corner. How can the Debug toolbar be enabled or disabled? Is there a configuration using which this can be controlled?

Comment: @George - I think this question is related to software development. The Debug toolbar in the question is useful for debugging **IdocScript** which is proprietary to this tool. And it is by default disabled. If a developer wants to develop new component for the Oracle Content Server, this debug tool will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/page_debugging_easier_in_ucm_11g), you probably have the IsPageDebug=1 parameter in your URL.

If that is not the case the option is probably set in the config.cfg file in your server, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e10807/a01_troubleshooting.htm) is the Oracle documentation about it.

Hope this help!

Comment: It works like charm. Adding &IsPageDebug=1 will enable the debug toolbar only for that page. If I click on a different page, it would show or not based on the default setting. But, the documentation you pointed me to mentions about controlling the overall setting - "You can also set the IsPageDebug variable in the config.cfg file if you want the setting to apply for the whole server."

Comment: Also many thanks for sending a link to Kyle's blog. I remember going through his article on debugging, but had trouble finding this article.